# Vertical alignment of multi column cells

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multicolumn

I'm working on a complicated table, having multiple columns and multiple rows and each column needs a fixed width. When a cell has a long sentence, I want the cell fixed in width, while other cells in the same row are aligned center vertically. I found a way using

```
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
```

but this doesn't work if the cell is multicolumned.

Here is my example:

```
\usepackage{multirow, hhline}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{rp{0.15\textwidth}p{0.15\textwidth}M{0.35\textwidth}M{0.25\textwidth}}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[0]{*}{}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{MultiColumn1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{MultiColumn2} \\
    \hhline{~----}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & column1 & column2 & column3 & column4 \\
    \hhline{-----}
    row1 & \multicolumn{2}{p{0.3\textwidth}}{\cellcolor{blue!25} I want this sentence vertically aligned in center} & Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence. & Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence. \\
    \hhline{-----}  
    row2 & Contents 1 & Contents 2 & Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence. & Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence. \\
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

It comes as below.
[image: Current problem]
I would like the sentence in the colored cell aligned vertically in center.
Does any one have an idea??

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost reach your goal :-). for centering blue colored cell you just need to use `\multicolumn{2}{M{0.3\textwidth}}{....}`. I allow myself to remove unnecessary code in your table. Also not use ``hhline˙package (I haven't installed it), anyway to my taste is nicer to use rules as defined in `booktab` package.

```
    \documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{multirow, hhline}
\usepackage{array,makecell,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{ragged2e}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{rp{0.15\textwidth}p{0.15\textwidth}
                 M{0.35\textwidth}M{0.25\textwidth}}
    \cmidrule[1pt]{2-5}      \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{MultiColumn1} 
                            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{MultiColumn2}    \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3}      \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    &   column1 &   column2 &   column3 &   column4                 \\
    \hline
row 1
    &   \multicolumn{2}{M{0.3\textwidth}}{\cellcolor{blue!25}
        I want this sentence vertically aligned in center}
        &   Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence.
            Here comes a long sentence.
            &   Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence.
                Here comes a long sentence.                        \\
    \hline
row 2
    &   Contents 1 &    Contents 2 &    Here comes a long sentence.
                                        Here comes a long sentence.
                                        Here comes a long sentence.
                                        &   Here comes a long sentence.
                                        Here comes a long sentence.
                                        Here comes a long sentence. \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
    \end{document}
```

Obtained table is:
[image]

I suggest you to look, if you like cell formatinng with `\Centering` as it provide package `ragged2e`. With it the text is centered, but long words are still hyphenated. With it you obtain:

[image]

**Edit:** Considering @LaRiFaRi comment, the alternative, nicer table you can obtain width:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,makecell,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc,ragged2e}
\usepackage{microtype}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{rp{0.15\textwidth}p{0.15\textwidth}
                 M{0.35\textwidth}M{0.25\textwidth}}
    \cmidrule[1pt]{2-5}      %\cmidrule(l){4-5}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{MultiColumn1} 
                            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{MultiColumn2}    \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3}      \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    &   column1 &   column2 &   column3 &   column4                 \\
    \hline
row 1
    &   \multicolumn{2}{M{0.3\textwidth+2\tabcolsep}}{\cellcolor{blue!25}
        I want this sentence vertically aligned in center}
        &   Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence.
            Here comes a long sentence.
            &   Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence.
                Here comes a long sentence.                        \\
    \hline
row 2
    &   Contents 1 &    Contents 2 &    Here comes a long sentence.
                                        Here comes a long sentence.
                                        Here comes a long sentence.
                                        &   Here comes a long sentence.
                                        Here comes a long sentence.
                                        Here comes a long sentence. \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Delete the first `\cmidrule(l){4-5}` which is wrong, load `microtype` and `caption`, and extend the blue box as said in my last comment of my answer. Then your second approach will be perfect.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, ah copy-past error. Of course it is superfluous. With microtype all will look even more  nicer. I will upgrade my unswer with your suggestion. And sory, when I already pres key `submit` I see, that already (now I see almost the same) answer.

Comment: Don't you worry. I just learned about `\Centering` from your answer. And I have this package loaded all the time... So that's worthy enough. +1

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much to both LaRiFaRi and Zarko!

Answer (score 2):

For me, `M` seems to work in `\multicolumn` or did I understand something wrong?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption} % better spacing around the caption

\begin{document}   
\setcounter{table}{1}   
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Add caption}\label{tab:addlabel}
    \begin{tabular}{rM{0.15\textwidth}M{0.15\textwidth}M{0.35\textwidth}M{0.25\textwidth}}
         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{MultiColumn1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{MultiColumn2} \\
        \hhline{~----}
        & column1 & column2 & column3 & column4 \\
        \hhline{-----}
        row1 & \multicolumn{2}{M{0.3\textwidth}}{\cellcolor{blue!25} I want this sentence vertically aligned in center} & Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence. & Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence. \\
        \hhline{-----}  
        row2 & Contents 1 & Contents 2 & Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence. & Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence. \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

However, I would recommend to load the package `calc` and to do `\multicolumn{2}{M{.3\textwidth+2\tabcolsep}}` instead.