# Struggling to display a table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow

I have been tasked to display a table that looks like follows:

[image: Caption]

Here is the LaTeX that generates such table:

```latex
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
Logo & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Type de fiche} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Date} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Dernier statut} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Localisation} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Degré d'urgence} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Images} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Carte} \\ \cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Inputs} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Logo incendie} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{Consignes correspondantes} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

It may be important to mention that the table is displayed in landscape mode.

However, I am struggling to define a column width (ie. column "E" should be 33% of the page's width, and so should the result of columns "A" + "B" be)

Here are my struggles :

- The cells "Type de fiche" and "Date" should be vertically centered
- The content inside "inputs" and "Consignes correspondantes" should be able to display on multiple lines instead of taking their required length.
- Both these cells should also be vertically centered too.

I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260855/vertical-alignment-of-multi-column-cells) that prove me that what I want to do seems feasible, but I'm a rookie at LaTeX and was not able to apply the solution to my problem.

I have created a MWE to show you how far I have been, but these 3 points are giving me lots of struggle.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

% Document
\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
        \topskip0pt
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \begin{table}[htb!]
            \centering
            \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
            \begin{tabular}{rp{0.15\textwidth}p{0.15\textwidth}M{0.35\textwidth}M{0.35\textwidth}}
                \rowcolor{red} \multicolumn{1}{c}{\includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{example-image.jpg}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\huge Fiche de protection} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{08/04/2022} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Évacué} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Au mur} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Urgence 1} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\includegraphics[height=5cm, width=5cm, keepaspectratio]{example-image.jpg} \includegraphics[height=5cm, width=5cm, keepaspectratio]{example-image.jpg}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\includegraphics[height=5cm, width=5cm, keepaspectratio]{example-image.jpg}} \\ \cline{1-4}
                \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\Large Liturgique Statue Marie} Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence. Here comes a long sentence. & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline %\qquad Influence : Liturgique    \qquad Classement : Non classé      \qquad Matière du bien : ["Bois"]   \qquad Poids : 12kg     \qquad Hauteur : 3m     \qquad Largeur : 2m     \qquad Profondeur : 10cm
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\includegraphics[height=5cm, width=5cm]{example-image.jpg}} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Extraction - 2 personne(s) requise(s). Matériel nécessaire : 8m x 0, Sangles à cliquets 7m x 4, Couvertures de déménagement x 2, Protection thermique 3m*5m x 1} \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
        \vspace*{\fill}
    \end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What does your MWE have to do with the desired table?   It generates a completely different table.

Comment: Sorry it's not clearer, the table's structure is supposed to look like the screenshot, but the actual result should be more like my MWE

Answer (score 1):

This should be a good start:

```
\begin{table}[tbp]
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
Logo & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Type de fiche} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Date} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|p{0.3\textwidth}|}{Dernier statut} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Localisation} & \multicolumn{1}{p{0.33\textwidth}|}{Degré d'urgence} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Images} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Carte} \\ \cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{4}{|p{0.6\textwidth}|}{Inputs: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent tempor eleifend ligula, non imperdiet mi. Duis at ipsum et ipsum tempor rutrum. Ut euismod nisl nec convallis blandit.} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Logo incendie} & \multicolumn{4}{p{0.75\textwidth}|}{Consignes correspondantes\newline
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent tempor eleifend ligula, non imperdiet mi. Duis at ipsum et ipsum tempor rutrum. Ut euismod nisl nec convallis blandit.} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The `0.75\textwidth` should be calculated from the width of `Logo incendie` and it should take into account the intercolumn widths (in total `6\tabcolsep`, I think.

[image]